# How to make eps file imported in .tex , un-cropped?

Tags: graphics, eps

I have a eps file with a very high resolution. Now when I am trying to import it in my tex file using include graphics I am only able to see part of it, i.e. its cropped. I already played with width, height, keepaspectratio which didn't help.

Here is my simplified tex file:

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
%   \advance\leftskip-3cm
%   \advance\rightskip-3cm
    \includegraphics[width=500pt]{Uniform.eps}
        \label{fig:Uniform}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image]

Comment: eps files are vectorial images, they don't have resolution like bmp files. I believe that the problem is with the bounding box. Try `\fbox{}` to insert the image inside, to see the box.

Comment: Well the underlying graph is not a vectorized graph but a picture...that is the reason that resolution matters

Comment: @Sigur how can I set sizes of an fbox? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Just use `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=500pt]{Uniform.eps}}` to see the box used by the image. Then you can try to fix your problem.

Comment: @Naji just go \fbox{\includegraphics[width=500pt]{Uniform.eps}}` If there is a lot of white space _inside_ the box then the bounding box in the file is oncorrect you can supply a correct one with [bb= 1 2 3 4, width=500pt]{Uniform.eps} where 1 and 2 are the coordinates of teh lower left corner and 3 4 is the top right

Comment: Same result. Cropped again! I can send you the eps file if it helps

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, actually there is no white space in the box but box is cropping the image again.

Comment: 11pt article class \textwidth is 360pt and you are specifying 500pt width so it is not going to fit.

Comment: That was it...I didn't realize it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11pt article class `\textwidth` is 360pt and you are specifying 500pt width so it is not going to fit.

You can use `[width=\textwidth]` to get a full width figure rather than specify a size in points.

Comment: in my simplified everything is working but in original one, its still cropped!!

Comment: you never said but cropped vertically or horizontally? if it is too high you need `[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepapectratio]`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @Naji you'll need to make another minimal example that _does_ show the problem and ask a new question.

Comment: What should I put for the title of the question??

Comment: title isn't that important what is more important is that you provide a complete reproducible example document that shows the problem.

Comment: @Naji, try to host your eps file to us.

Comment: I found the source of problem but I don't know how to fix it! Its the XeLaTeX that I use in the original file! So in LaTeX, \textwidth helps but in XeLaTeX it doesn't

Comment: I still can send the file, but I think now that I told you the source, there is no need to. Right?

Comment: @Naji `\textwidth` works the same way in xelatex and pdflatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, well for the same code, XeLaTeX doesn't work but LaTeX works. Do you want me to share the file here?

Comment: @Naji sorry I'm shutting down for the night:-)

Comment: Maybe some option to the `graphicx` package would be necessary?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Then I am really out of luck! Cause tonight is my deadline to change this thing.

Comment: @Sigur, well if you have any idea I would be happy to hear it and give it a shut.

Comment: Try to pass the option `pdflatex` to the `graphicx` package.

Comment: I get Option clash!
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{ulem,cancel,subfigure}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm,fontspec}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,matrix,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage[pdflatex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{hyperref}

Comment: I realized the only package needing xelatex is fontspec. Is there anyway to avoid using fontspec and using something else instead?

Comment: Try `pdftex`. If not, so I have no idea.

Comment: Actually I just tried LauLaTeX and it worked!! :)